# Ubuntu 14.04 laptop and monitor problem

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, laptop, resolution

I meet with this problem second time. I'm using a laptop with dual boot. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Win7. I have a 21,5" monitor plugged with HDMI cable to my notebook.

I did this:

- my laptop was turned off and monitor wasn't plugged
- I turned on my laptop
- I chose Ubuntu in grub menu
- I plugged my monitor
- I closed my laptop lid
- The monitor had black screen
- I wait few minutes and I opened my laptop lid
- both monitor got a screen. I've seen the Ubuntu desktop.
- I closed my laptop lid.
- Monitor turned to black screen

And after that I couldn't use my monitor on native resolution (1920x1080). I see the highest resolution in display settings, but it doesn't work. I can use it only with 1440x900 resolution. It doesn't work on Windows 7 neither. Earlier I formatted my laptop and reinstalled the operation systems and it worked well again. I would like to avoid this method.

`lshw -c video` result:

```
*-display

   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GF108M [GeForce GT 420M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:b3080000-b30fffff
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Yea of course. Done

Comment: Thanks, you had a good sense to write down that command. :) The version number is: 346.35. I used the apt-get install nvidia-current yesterday.

Comment: I did. Both monitor had a black screen while the notebook was booting and after that I've seen the desktop only on the monitor. Notebook had a black screen. I tried the higher resolution but it still black only 1440x900 works.

Comment: Mirroring is off and the checkbox is read only.

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10484184/

Comment: Don't thank me yet.  I'll convert this to an answer and then you can thank me by accepting it...

Comment: I've deleted all of my comments and so should you to keep things uncluttered so that the next person that has the same problem as you can benefit from out work!  ;-)  Please don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your current [monitors.xml](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10484184/) contains an a bunch of monitors you tried in the past or that got created by the system during updates, please save the [following file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10519498) to monitors.new.

The second file just contains your original configuration when installing the system and all other configurations have just been deleted.

Now reboot, Log into the console by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][F1], and type the following commands:

```
mv /home/YourUser/.config/monitors.xml /home/YourUser/.config/monitors.old
mv /home/YourUser/.config/monitors.new /home/YourUser/.config/monitors.xml
```

The first command saves your existing monitors.xml to monitors.old and the second renames monitors.new to monitors.xml

Then just reboot and log on.

Everything should then be in a working condition again!  ;-)